# problem with fullCalendar sending Z in UTC dates when calling API using fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I used to use FullCalendar v3 and I am trying to upgrade it to v6 but it has many differences. So the issue is that I have this code:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            timeZone: user_timezone,
            events: '/schedule/api/occurrences?calendar_slug=' + '{{request.user}}',
            eventClick: function(info) {},
            .....
       });
       calendar.render();
});
```

I've made the required modifications so it can work on v6 but the issue here is the endpoint.
On v3 no matter what the timezone was the start and end date were always rendered correctly. An example endpoint on v3 is this :

```
http://0.0.0.0:6666/schedule/api/occurrences?calendar_slug=admin&timezone=Pacific%2FPitcairn&start=2023-08-27&end=2023-10-08
```

But now on v6 when I load the code shown above the endpoint the datetime renders differently based on the timezone. if the timezone is in UTC (which is where my problem comes from) the url looks like this (Has Z or if set in `local` -+hours):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/schedule/api/occurrences?calendar_slug=admin&start=2023-08-27T00:00:00Z&end=2023-10-08T00:00:00Z&timeZone=UTC
```

which funny enough returns error `uncoverted data remaing:Z`. In other timezones it works correctly (timezone loads without Z so it is readable).
I tried setting `timeZone: 'local'` and then rendering it but still nothing.
What I need is to load the date as shown on the first example, without UTC offset.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: The Z is a valid character in an ISO8601 date/time string and does indeed denote that the date is in UTC. Your API should be able to understand it. That is what needs fixing. fullCalendar isn't really doing anything wrong. If you did want the ability for fullCalendar not to do sent it, you'd probably need to [request a feature](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) where you have the option to turn it off.

Comment: For a shorter-term fix, if for some reason you cannot amend the API code, I would suggest changing to use a [callback function as the event source](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) so you can construct your own AJAX request and set the parameters yourself, including formatting the date strings as you wish.

Comment: See also https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html

Comment: the events contain only the slug so it automatically takes the start and end date and adding the Z for UTC. isnt this a problem from the  fullCalendar API directly? I'll try doing it as an ajax instead

Comment: `it automatically takes the start and end date and adding the Z`.... I know. `isnt this a problem from the fullCalendar API `... no it's not a fullCalendar problemm because, as I said before, it's a _perfectly valid thing to do in an ISO8601 date string_. If your server-side API code cannot cope with that, then your server code has a problem!

Comment: But yes if you want you can make your own AJAX request instead, so you've got more control over what exactly is sent to the server.